# Poisson point process about watering

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

> On average, there are $100$ rainy days per year. The rainy days are instantaneous and arrive according to a Poisson point process. Jack waters his flowers if they haven't been watered in the last $48$ hours (by rain or by Jack).
>
> - What is the distribution of the number of rainy days between two watering by Jack?
> - What is the expected time that elapses between two waterings by Jack?
> - Roughly how many times does Jack water his flowers manually this year?

I'm stuck with solving this problem. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: From the Poisson point process assumption, we know that the inter-arrival time between rainy days follow an exponential distribution. Suppose Jack water at certain time $t_0$. That implies that the last rainy day happen at least $2$ days before $t_0$ (actually it does not matter due to the memory-less property of exponential). Now you just need to show that the time between the arrival time of next rainy day and $t_0$ is also the same exponential. Next, note that if the rainy day arrive within 2 days from the previous rainy day, then you continue to wait; otherwise Jack will water..